# Loading RWeka on RStudio causes fatal error

Tags: r, rstudio, rweka

```
require(RWeka)
```

and

```
library(RWeka)
```

is creating a fatal error in R session.Restart the session.
Any reasons or solutions for the same??

Comment: Just to confirm, did you install RWeka before loading?

Comment: It works fine for me, you'll need to provide more information so that we have a chance of knowing what's wrong on your system.

Comment: What information do i give which can help in figuring out whats wrong.

Comment: What happens if you try to load the `RWeka` package in a vanilla R session (outside of RStudio)?